# NSScanner memory leak

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks

I'm at my first experiences with iPhone development.
I wrote some basic code to test the NSScanner class, and now I was looking into the Leaks tool. It seems that this code is leaking, when in the detailed stack I double-click my last call (before Apple's stuff), the incriminated line is the commented.

Can anyone help me to understand why this is leaking? from a logical point of view the result is what I expect, and I do not formally alloc anything myself (except for the xmlblock variable, which is btw autoreleased), so I would not expect the need to release anything... where I'm wrong? :-)

```
+(NSSet *)extractXMLSectionsWithTag:(NSString *)tag fromString:(NSString *)source firstOnly:(BOOL)firstOnly
{
 if (!source)
    return nil;
 NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:source];
 NSString *openingToken = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%@", tag];
 NSString *closingToken = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"</%@>", tag];
 NSMutableSet *sections = [NSMutableSet set];
 NSCharacterSet *majorChar = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@">"];

 while (![scanner isAtEnd]) {
    NSString *xmlBlock = [[[NSString alloc] init] autorelease];
    [scanner scanUpToString:openingToken intoString:NULL];
    [scanner scanString:openingToken intoString:NULL];
    [scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:majorChar intoString:NULL];
    [scanner scanCharactersFromSet:majorChar intoString:NULL];
    [scanner scanUpToString:closingToken intoString:&xmlBlock];
    if (![xmlBlock isEqualToString:@""]) { // Leaking line
        [sections addObject:xmlBlock];
        if (firstOnly) {
            break;
        }
    }
 }
 return [sections copy];
}
```

Comment: By the way, you don't need to create a blank string for `scanUpToString:intoString:`, you can just set it to `nil`, and the method will change it if it scans text. Another potentially useful thing is that all those `NSScanner` methods return a boolean value based on whether they succeeded or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the leak is caused by returning [sections copy], from a method like that you are supposed to return an autoreleased string - not a retained one.

In XCode choose the "Build & Analyze" option and see what it says about this code.

Comment: Yes that was the problem, many thanks, it wasn't clear to me thay the copy message creates a retained object (I was fooled by thinking that I was not calling any init message, so it was not my duty to release... but copying is actually a creaton, of course). I changed the last line to "return [[sections copy] autorelease], and the leak does not show up anymore!

Comment: Actually, you can just return "sections" since it is autoreleased already.  No need to copy and then autorelease, as it has the same effect...

Comment: The final copy was (in my mind) to return an immutable version, to avoid any overhead the mutable version could carry on... is this wrong or useless?

Comment: It's not exactly wrong, it's just a wash compared to the extra resources you use to create the copy... however that said I do usually use copy on the other side, at least for NSString properties.  There I like to have a clearer picture when the string I am using was really allocated.  Because you mostly return autoreleased objects I like to leave it up to the caller to decide if it's worth the expense of making a copy, the caller does not know what you are returning is mutable so there's no danger there.
If the value were meant to be accessed by different threads later on, then I would copy.

Comment: Got it, I has a suspect about the overhead of copying, but the suggestion to leave the caller decide seems a very good design approach, thanks!